# Scrollbar arrows missing

Tags: html, css

i have a little problem with css and html. i'd like to build a page with dynamic height of an article where the scrollbar only appears when there is more content then the window height.

The problem now is that **i miss the bottom arrow of the scroll bar.** i at least found out that it occurs because the header has 30px height and the article is 100% in height of its parrent element which is the body.

```
<body>
    <header>HEADER</header>
    <article>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </article>
</body>
```

With CSS i put in the style as follows:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
header{
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #f00;
    line-height:30px;
}
article{
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

First i thought, that i can fix it by making the position of the header fixed and set the padding-top to 30px. but that did not help and i dont want to mess around with paddings and margins to solve a problem in my structure.

may be somebody of you can help me fixing my problem. because i got no idead how to go on.

here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/

dears,
Daniel

EDIT: The header should stay fixed, but without using position fixed, since i would get the same problem when using padding-bottom at the article.

EDIT2: Beside the good solution from dm4web in the solution-post, i build up the solution stated in comments. http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/13/ to fit my tasks.

Comment: You should let the body scroll and use position:fixed on the header instead http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/2/

Comment: This is a very simplified example, where the header is just 30px in height. If I go further and set the position to fixed and add a padding-bottom to the article, then I would have the same problem. using fixed position though would not make it up for me.

Comment: To handle the padding you'd have to have `box-sizing:border-box`, but that is a completely separate issue. Fixing the header is the best way to go - that's what it was designed for

Comment: I see, but now i have the problem, that when there is less content in the article, that i still have a scrollbar, which i dont want to. http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/10/

Comment: You'd have to apply `box-sizing:border-box` to the body as well. http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/11/ You should read the docs on the subject

Comment: that makes up for it... thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Wrap header and article with div
2. remove html, body style overflow
3. add overflow to the div: `div{ overflow: hidden;}`

[jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/12/)

**EDIT2:**

http://jsfiddle.net/o8xspprd/12/

```
article{height: calc(100% - 30px);}
```

Comment: Your fiddle isn't working. i tried it myself, but then i got the whole page scrolling. but i'd like to have only the article scrolling.
http://jsfiddle.net/kd9sn2s7/1/

Comment: checked it, and bottom arrow is missing on scrollbar.

Comment: only if you use a calc in css style like in EDIT2

Comment: definitly the easiest way i think. thanks. :) cant upvote to positive value, somebody downvoted. -.-